# Regex to parse sudoers User_Spec

Tags: regex, sudoers

Here is a sample `User_Spec`:

```
AOPS          TRUSTED_HOSTS=(sysexec) ALL, (sqlexec) ALL : \
              A_HOSTS=(root) SMF, \
              (root) /usr/local/sbin/install-soft, \
              (root) /usr/sbin/umount /db/test, \
              (root) /usr/sbin/mount * : \
               master=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsh slave[0-9] netstat, \
              (root) /usr/bin/rsh syshost[a-z]*[0-9] hostname, \
              (root) PASSWD:/usr/bin/rsh syshost[a-z]*[0-9] stats*, \
              (root) /bin/netstat, \
              (root) /sbin/mount -o nosuid, \
              (root) NIS, \
              (sysuser) /usr/local/bin/cvs commit syblogin : \
              A_QA_HOSTS=(root) NOPASSWD:  /usr/bin/, !SU, !SHELLS :\
              slave10.example.com=(root) /proj/systems/database/sqlrefresh/bin/sqlrefresh.run
```

I want to parse this and the output should be like:

```
AOPS : TRUSTED_HOSTS        : sysexec : ALL
AOPS : TRUSTED_HOSTS        : sqlexec : ALL
AOPS :  A_HOSTS             : root    : SMF , /usr/local/sbin/install-soft, /usr/sbin/umount /db/test, /usr/sbin/mount *
AOPS :  A_HOSTS             : sysexec : /usr/bin/du 
AOPS :  master.example.com  : root    : /usr/bin/rsh slave[0-9] netstat , /usr/bin/rsh syshost[a-z]*[0-9] hostname , 
                                        /usr/bin/rsh syshost[a-z]*[0-9] stats*,/bin/netstat , /sbin/mount -o nosuid , NIS
AOPS :  master.example.com  : sysexec : /usr/local/bin/cvs commit syblogin
AOPS :  A_QA_HOSTS          : root    : /usr/bin/, !SU, !SHELLS 
AOPS :  slave10.example.com : root    : /db/run/refresh
```

The delimiter between two host aliases is `:`, but `Tag_Spec` also has colon appended to them like `NOPASSWD:` or `EXEC:`. So I am not sure how to parse this.

Any help with the regex?

Comment: seems like a tough job. What did you tried?

Comment: I tried :
alias = re.split(r'^\s*(\S+)(.*)',line) - to extract the UserAlias
re.split(r'\s*(\S+\s*=\s*\(\w+\))+',alias[2]) - to split the host aliases
But not sure, if this is the right way to go.

Comment: I doubt we can help you without knowing **exactly** what you want. Even if we can _somewhat_ figure out what you want to extract, that's not enough to build a reliable regex pattern. E.g. where does `/usr/bind, !SU, !SHELLS` come from? Is that the text after `NOPASSWD:`, or is it the text after `A_QA_HOSTS=(root) \w+: `, or something else entirely? And then there are even greater mysteries: Where do `sysexec : /usr/bin/du ` and `root    : /db/run/refresh` come from?